# How does iOS decide whether or not opportunistic background fetch did download anything?

Tags: ios, ios7, background, fetch

In the Apple documentation about 'Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically' (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56) the following is written:

> Apps that download small amounts of content quickly, and accurately
>   reflect when they had content available to download, **are more likely
>   to receive execution time in the future** than apps that take a long
>   time to download their content or that claim content was available but
>   then do not download anything.
>
> When downloading any content, it is recommended that you use the
>   NSURLSession class to initiate and manage your downloads.

How does iOS decide whether there was something downloaded or not, if I am not using NSURLSession? The communication between my app and our backend happens over XMPP. I'm afraid that maybe iOS would think that nothing wasn't downloaded and limit execution time in the future, even if we did retrieve content over the XMPP socket.